# What does this addon-sdk implementation expect as param to access addon filesystem?

Tags: javascript, file-io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, trigger.io

I'm messing around with trigger.io's browser extensions framework. It's using [addon-sdk](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) when creating .xpi's for Firefox. The tidbit in question is from a [main JS file](http://pastebin.com/XjyRrzcZ) which wraps the API for later use elsewhere by the extension developers. Relevant bit:

```
var data = require("self").data;
// other stuff
var apiImpl = {
  // other APIs here
  file: {
    string: function (b, c, a) {
      c(data.load(b.uri.substring(data.url("").length)))
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like `data.load()` [expects a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self) like `resource://rabblerabble-at-jetpack/f/data/src/a.json`.

What's with the `b.uri.substring(data.url("").length))`? What's the point of that? 
I had to go digging to figure out why I had to send

```
forge.file.string({uri:'resource://rabblerabble-at-jetpack/f/data/src/a.json'}, function(data) {
  toLog(data);
}, function(e) {toError(e)});
```

Instead of simply sending the string as the first param.

I have a feeling it's expecting some commonly-used object which you can call a `.uri()` on but if that's the case I've no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like `data.load()` expects a string like `resource://rabblerabble-at-jetpack/f/data/src/a.json`.

`data.url("")` returns `resource://rabblerabble-at-jetpack/f/data/`. So

`b.uri.substring(data.url("").length)` returns `src/a.json`, which is what [`data.load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data) expects.

The [self module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self) has a `uri` property. So maybe the `forge.file.string()` is structured like that so that it can accept `self` as a parameter. That's my best guess without being able to see all the code.